# How to override default style on an input textbox

Tags: html, css

I have a default style like this:

```
input[type="text"] 
{ width: 250px; }
```

Now I have a input box that I want to have 450 width, how can I do this?

I've tried:

```
#searchbox 
{

width: 450px;
}


<input type="text" value="" name="asb" id="searchbox">
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Just make sure your rule is more specific than the default like so:

```
input[type="text"]#searchbox {
    width: 450px;
}
```

Comment: @Blankman: Nope; that would look for a input[type="text"] descendant of #searchbox.